# Issue while running infinite Loop

Tags: python-3.x

```
var = 1
while var == 1:
    num = input("Enter a number :")
    print ("You entered: ",num)
    var = num
print("Good bye!")
```

Loop should continue after entering `1` but it's getting terminated after that.

Please someone suggest for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I read inputs as integers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/how-can-i-read-inputs-as-integers)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try to cast it to integer? Like so:

```
num = int(input("Enter a number :"))
```

If this doesn't work you may try with booleans instead.

Comment: Here is similar problem: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/input-integers-python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449427/input-integers-python)

Answer (score 0):

```
  while True: 
     num=raw_input("enter number") 
     print float(num)
```